# "TypeError: $(...).sibling is not a function" weird jQuery error

Tags: jquery

This code here:

```
if (!$("#" + index).sibling('span').eq(0).hasClass("text-error")) 
{
    $("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value + '</span>');
}
```

is giving me this error:
`TypeError: $(...).sibling is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/ - correct name matters

Answer (score 1):

You need `siblings` check documentation http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: To expand on this: The error you're getting means a function (in thís case `sibling()` does not exist. 90% of the times the functionname has a typo (like now), or is not included in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the called function does not exist.

And that's no wonder since it's named siblings (plural): http://api.jquery.com/siblings/